# max of row records as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE test_max (
number_a INT,
number_b INT,
number_c INT,
)

GO
INSERT INTO test_max VALUES(3,7,9)
INSERT INTO test_max VALUES(5,2,10)
INSERT INTO test_max VALUES(31,4,91)
INSERT INTO test_max VALUES(35,124,1)
GO

select number_a,number_b,number_c from test_max
```

I want to print a fourth column which is max(number_a.value,number_b.value,number_c.value)

so the output should be like

```
3 7 9   9
5 2 10 10
31 4 91 91
35 124 1 124
```

Is it possible to do without using PIVOT as the columns maybe more than just 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `MAX` equivalent for row like `GREATEST` in `MySQL/Oracle`:

```
SELECT number_a,number_b,number_c, c.s AS greatest
FROM #test_max
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(v)
             FROM (VALUES (number_a),(number_b),(number_c)) AS c(v)
             ) AS c(s)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394464)**</kbd>

If you use version below `SQL Server 2008` use:

```
SELECT number_a,number_b,number_c, c.s AS greatest
FROM #test_max
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(v)
             FROM (SELECT number_a AS v
                   UNION ALL SELECT number_b
                   UNION ALL SELECT number_c
                  ) AS c(v)
             ) AS c(s);
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ number_a ║ number_b ║ number_c ║ Greatest ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║        3 ║        7 ║        9 ║        9 ║
║        5 ║        2 ║       10 ║       10 ║
║       31 ║        4 ║       91 ║       91 ║
║       35 ║      124 ║        1 ║      124 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

How it works:

1. Create derived table(subquery) with row values as table `VALUES/UNION ALL`
2. Get `MAX` value from derived table
3. Do it for each row in table 
   [`Using APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)